# Como selecionar maior numero de registros com base em outra tabela SQL

Tags: sql, select, sintaxe

Eu tenho uma tabela IMOVEIS

```
ID   |   Tipo   | endereço
1    |  Casa    | Rua teste
2    |  Casa    | Rua teste
3    |  Apartamento    | Rua teste
```

E uma tabela de vendas

```
id | ID_do imovel
1  | 1
2  | 2
```

Eu preciso saber com base na tabela de vendas, qual foi o tipo de imovel mais vendido da tabela IMOVEIS. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    i.Tipo AS Tipo,
    COUNT (i.Tipo) AS Quantidade
FROM
    IMOVEIS i INNER JOIN Vendas v ON i.ID = v.ID_do_Imovel
GROUP BY
    i.Tipo
```

Comment: Deus certo, mas ele me retornou todos os tipos e eu queria apenas o mais vendido, pra isso eu coloquei  ORDER BY total DESC limit 1